# Remain just that

Tags: meaning

I have been reading an article which reads as follows:

> I remember them well: those heavy black books with their glossy gold
>   lettering, all 32 of them... Anything I wanted to know ... my grandfather would look for in there, his prized set of
>   Encyclopedia Britannica.
>
> But such a memory will, from now on, **remain just that**.

What is the meaning of the last phrase? That it will remain a memory and printed Encyclopedia Britannica is no more?

Comment: The *that* refers back to *such a memory*. They mean to say that the memory will remain just a memory and nothing more.

Comment: "That it will remain a memory and printed Encyclopedia Britannica is no more?" Yep.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, "Remain just that", refers to the memory itself.  In essence what it is saying is,

> But such a memory will, from now on, remain just that: a memory.

Now, in passing, it may seem quite obvious that a memory will remain a memory.  After all, most immutable things remain those things.  However, the writer has chosen these words to reinforce the finality of his experiences with his grandfather by saying that this memory will always be a memory and nothing more.

Answer (score -2):

This is telling the reader that now, the authors Grandfather is dead. It is a roundabout way of saying it, it does so by saying that this action, of consulting the Encylopedia with his Grandfather can not happen again, *will remain a memory*.